# Strange variable assignment in Swift with RemObjects Silver

Tags: swift, remobjects

I'm trying to convert a String to a Char array in Swift. I use RemObjects' Silver compiler with Visual Studio. However, printing the array doesn't give the same result wether using an intermediate variable or not!

```
var text: String = Console.ReadLine().uppercaseString()
var textChar = [Char](text)

for var index = 0; index < textChar.count; index++ {
    println(textChar[index]) // Correct
    var a = textChar[index]  // Wrong result
    println(a)
}
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I have no experience with that compiler, but in any case, you should provide a concrete example of input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: What version of the compiler are you using? and what platform — i assume, from the `Console.ReadLine()`, .NET? This snippet doesn't compile for me at all, for various good reasons.

Comment: This code compiles for me:

http://paste.ie/view/5e93ee11
and prints the same value twice for each char, as expected (for value ASCII chars)